# Guest OS in Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So they say that, Docker is different because it does not use Guest OS, but Host OS instead.

And in the meantime they themselves include Guest OS as Base Image in their DockerFiles.

Either they have dual personality, or I am not smart. What am I understanding wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Docker's early container idea was taken from [containerd](https://containerd.io/) on Linux.(The latest version has its own container technology, but the function is similar.
)

containerd (used by Docker) isolate containers using Linux namespaces and use other operating system features such as cgroups, seccomp filters, and capabilities to restrict what the contained process can do. All the containers running on a single VM share a single operating system kernel.

containerd also provides an environment where guest os can operate within the host os by providing an isolated space from the host by separating os resources and networks.